# How can I integrate swagger with laravel

Tags: laravel, swagger, openapi

I integrated **open API** with **Laravel**  then by visiting this route **http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login** I Expects response body json like this

```
{
 message: "you have signedup"
}
```

but the actual result right now is **419** with unreadable contents see below

```
<html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Page Expired</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body class="antialiased">
        <div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center sm:pt-0">
            <div class="max-w-xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="flex items-center pt-8 sm:justify-start sm:pt-0">
                    <div class="px-4 text-lg text-gray-500 border-r border-gray-400 tracking-wider">
                        419                    </div>

                    <div class="ml-4 text-lg text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        Page Expired                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That error likely comes from Laravel's [CSRF protection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf). It is very difficult to tell you why without knowing how "I integrated open API with Laravel". To improve, check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I correct this question by saving collection using `postman` later on I exported `openApi.yml` file by using[apimatic](https://apimatic.io) apimatic.io
then I integrated it with Laravel app, in `resources/view/welcome.blade.ph`

### steps to export on apimatic

- signup to apimatic then import json exported collection from postman
- click on transofrm api
- Click proceed then your choose swagger/openApi v2
- yaml file exported has all documentation you need but you customize it however you want